# Is there any stotram related to shri ram naam by other gods

Tags: shiva, rama, padma-purana

In padmapuran and skandpuran, mahadev gives a proper idea about how great is ram naam. But has there been any other deva except mahadev that gave more importance of ram naam

Answer (score 1):

By the way, many deities have sung the glory of Shri Ram. The most prominent among them is Lord Shiva and Lord Shri Krishna.We are all familiar with Lord Shiva, today I will introduce you to Lord Shri Krishna, what he has said about the name of Shri Ram.

**अथ श्रीपद्मपुराण वर्णित रामनामामृत स्त्रोत श्रीकृष्ण अर्जुन संवाद~**

*अर्जुन उवाच~*

१)
भुक्तिमुक्तिप्रदातृणां सर्वकामफलप्रदं ।

सर्वसिद्धिकरानन्त नमस्तुभ्यं जनार्दन ॥

अर्थ:~ सभी भोग और मुक्ति के फल दाता, सभी कर्मों का फल देने वाले, सभी कार्य को सिद्ध करने वाले जनार्दन मैं आपको नमन करता हूं।

२)
यं कृत्वा श्री जगन्नाथ मानवा यान्ति सद्गतिम् ।

ममोपरि कृपां कृत्वा तत्त्वं ब्रहिमुखालयम्।।

अर्थ:~हे श्रीजगन्नाथ! मनुष्य ऐसा क्या करें कि उसे अंत में सद्गति हो? वह तत्व क्या है? मेरे पर कृपा करके अपने ब्रह्ममुख से बताइए।

**श्रीकृष्ण उवाच~**

१)
यदि पृच्छसि कौन्तेय सत्यं सत्यं वदाम्यहम् ।

लोकानान्तु हितातार्थाय इह लोके परत्र च ॥

अर्थ:~ हे कुंती पुत्र! यदि तुम मुझसे पूछते हो तो मैं सत्य सत्य बताता हूं, इस लोक और परलोक में हित करने वाला क्या है।

२)
रामनाम सदा पुण्यं नित्यं पठति यो नरः ।

अपुत्रो लभते पुत्रं सर्वकामफलप्रदम् ॥

अर्थ:~श्रीराम का नाम सदा पुण्य करने वाला नाम है, जो मनुष्य इसका नित्य पाठ करता है उसे पुत्र लाभ मिलता है और सभी कामनाएं पूर्ण होती है।

३)
मङ्गलानि गृहे तस्य सर्वसौख्यानि भारत।

अहोरात्रं च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~हे भारत! उसके घर में सभी प्रकार के सुख और मंगल विराजित हो जाते हैं, जिसने दिन-रात श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का उच्चारण कर लिया।

४)
गङ्गा सरस्वती रेवा यमुना सिन्धु पुष्करे।

केदारेतूदकं पीतं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ॥

अर्थ~जिसने श्रीरामनाम के इन दो अक्षरों का उच्चारण कर लिया उसने श्रीगंगा, सरस्वती, रेवा, यमुना, सिंधु, पुष्कर, केदारनाथ आदि सभी तीर्थों का स्नान, जलपान कर लिया।

५)
अतिथेः पोषणं चैव सर्व तीर्थावगाहनम् ।

सर्वपुण्यं समाप्नोति रामनाम प्रसादतः ।।

अर्थ:~उसने अतिथियों का पोषण कर लिया, सभी तीर्थों में स्नान आदि कर लिया, उसने सभी पुण्य कर्म कर लिए जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

६)
सूर्यपर्व कुरुक्षेत्रे कार्तिक्यां स्वामि दर्शने।

कृपापात्रेण वै लब्धं येनोक्तमक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~उसने सूर्य ग्रहण के समय कुरुक्षेत्र में स्नान कर लिया और कार्तिक पूर्णिमा में कार्तिक जी का दर्शन करके कृपा प्राप्त कर ली जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

७)
न गंङ्गा न गया काशी नर्मदा चैव पुष्करम् ।

सदृशं रामनाम्नस्तु न भवन्ति कदाचन।।

अर्थ:~ ना तो गंगा, गया, काशी, प्रयाग, पुष्कर, नर्मदादिक इन सब में कोई भी श्रीराम नाम की महिमा के समक्ष नहीं हो सकते।

८)
येन दत्तं हुतं तप्तं सदा विष्णुः समर्चितः।

जिह्वाग्रे वर्तते यस्य राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम्।।

अर्थ:~उसने भांति-भांति के हवन, दान, तप और विष्णु भगवान की आराधना कर ली, जिसकी जिह्वा के अग्रभाग पर श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर विराजित हो गए।

९)
माघस्नानं कृतं येन गयायां पिण्डपातनम् ।

सर्वकृत्यं कृतं तेन येनोक्तं रामनामकम्।।

अर्थ:~ उसने प्रयागजी में माघ का स्नान कर लिया, गयाजी में पिंडदान कर लिया उसने अपने सभी कार्यों को पूर्ण कर लिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम का उच्चारण कर लिया।

१०)
प्रायश्चित्तं कृतं तेन महापातकनाशनम् ।

तपस्तप्तं च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने अपने सभी महापापों का नाश करके प्रायश्चित कर लिया और तपस्या पूर्ण कर ली जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर का उच्चारण कर लिया।

११)
चत्वारः पठिता वेदास्सर्वे यज्ञाश्च याजिताः ।

त्रिलोकी मोचिता तेन राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने चारों वेदों का सांगोपांग पाठ कर लिया सभी यज्ञ आदि कर्म कर लिए उसने तीनों लोगों को तार दिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षर का पाठ कर लिया।

१२)
भूतले सर्व तीर्थानि आसमुद्रसरांसि च।

सेवितानि च येनोक्तं राम इत्यक्षरद्वयम् ।।

अर्थ~उसने भूतल पर सभी तीर्थ, समुद्र, सरोवर आदि का सेवन कर लिया जिसने श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का जाप कर लिया।

**अर्जुन उवाच~**

१)
यदा म्लेच्छमयी पृथ्वी भविष्यति कलौयुगे ।

किं करिष्यति लोकोऽयं पतितो रौरवालये ।।

अर्थ~भविष्य में कलयुग आने पर पूरी पृथ्वी मलेच्छ मयी हो जाएगी इसका स्वरूप रौ-रौ नर्क की भांति हो जाएगा तब जीव कौन सा साधन करके परम पद पाएगा?

**श्रीकृष्ण उवाच~**

१)
न सन्देहस्त्वया काय्र्यो न वक्तव्यं पुनः पुनः ।

पापी भवति धर्मात्मा रामनाम प्रभावतः ।।

अर्थ~यह संदेह करने योग्य नहीं है, जैसे संदेह व्यर्थ है वैसे बार-बार वक्तव्य देना भी व्यर्थ है। कैसा भी पापी हो श्रीराम नाम के प्रभाव से वह धर्मात्मा हो जाता है

२)
न म्लेच्छस्पर्शनात्तस्य पापं भवति देहिनः ।

तस्मात्प्रमुच्यते जन्तुर्यस्मरेद्रामद्वचत्तरम् ।।

अर्थ~उसे मलेच्छ के स्पर्श का भी पाप नहीं होता, मलेच्छ संबंधित पाप भी छूट जाते हैं जो श्रीराम नाम के दो अक्षरों का जाप करते हैं।

३)
रामस्तत्वमधीयानः श्रद्धाभक्तिसमन्वितः।

कुलायुतं समुद्धृत्य रामलोके महीयते ।।

अर्थ~जो श्रीराम से संबंध रखने वाले स्त्रोत का पाठ करते हैं तथा जिनकी भक्ति, विश्वास और श्रद्धा श्रीराम में सुदृढ़ है। वह लोग अपने दस हज़ार पीढ़ियों का उद्धार करके श्रीराम के लोक में पूजित होते है।

४)
रामनामामृतं स्तोत्रं सायं प्रातः पठेन्नरः ।

गोघ्नः स्त्रीबालघाती च सर्व पापैः प्रमुच्यते ।।

अर्थ~जो सुबह शाम इस रामनामामृत स्त्रोत का पाठ करते हैं वे गौ हत्या, स्त्री और बच्चों को हानि पहुंचाने वाले पाप से भी बच कर मुक्त हो जाते हैं।

**(इति श्रीपद्मपुराणे रामनामामृत स्त्रोते श्रीकृष्ण अर्जुन संवादे संपूर्णम्)**

Comment: Please translate the meaning of stotra into English.

Comment: Its not possible for me to translate it now you can translate from google. I hope you understand my point.

Comment: But answers are not accepted in other languages other than English@Shiv